# Automate emails sending - Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

Is there a way to send emails after a specified date ?, for example send email to a user to inform it before licence expiration.

NB : I'm using Laravel 4

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options

1. Queue an email using the inbuilt [Laravel Queue system](http://laravel.com/docs/queues),

   $date = Carbon::now()->addDays(3);
   Queue::later($date, 'SendEmail@send', array('message' => $message));
2. Run a daily cron script, which calls an artisan command that checks all users, and checks their licence expiration. If the licence is expired - send them an email

Personally I think option 2 will probably be best.

Comment: I think i will use the method 2, can you give me some details how i can do that?. Thank you